# FBRequest get parameters issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I want to get in my app info about the user. His name, age, location, gender, profile image and other stuff.

For now i am using :

```
-(void)facebookOpenSession{
FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[me startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                 id result,
                                 NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *resultDic = (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *) result;
    facebookData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:resultDic];

    FBRequest *pic = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/?fields=picture"];
    [pic startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                     id result,
                                     NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *resultDic = (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *) result;

        NSDictionary *dic = [resultDic objectForKey:@"picture"];
        NSDictionary *dic2 = [dic objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *imgUrl = [dic2 objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(imgUrl);
    }];
}];
```

}

I made two requests ine for the user profile and one other for the image, and i want to know if i can make only one call? and if i want to get another info what i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you annotated your code is a little weird to read for me, so I re-wrote it like so:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             self.nameString = user.name;
             self.profileImage.profileID = user.id;
             self.userName = user.username;
         }
     }];
}
```

It really isn't much more complicated than how I wrote it.

Happy Coding!

**Addition to code due to comments:**

You need to get the output from Facebook. For an image, your code should look like:

```
FBProfilePictureView *profileImage.profileID = user.id;
```

`user.id` comes from Facebook once you initiate an `FBRequest`.

You don't really convert the `FBProfilePictureView` into a `UIImageView`, but instead, set the `FBProfilePictureView` as a subview of a `UIView` that you create.

Also, you need to set the picture cropping:

```
profileImage.pictureCropping = FBProfilePictureCroppingSquare;
```

`FBProfilePictureCroppingSquare` is one of a few choices that you have. Read up on the documentation in [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBProfilePictureView) to see your options.